# Solving for variable in quotient of ceil function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given $k=\lceil\frac m {n}\rceil$, I would like to solve for $m$ given $k$ and $n$ as positive integers.  How do I solve for $m$, and is there a single solution for $m$?

Perhaps one way to do this might be to split $n$ up into cases depending on whether it is even or odd?  However, I've noticed that this does not always work, and I think there might be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: The solutions are $nk$, $nk - 1$, ..., $nk - n + 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $m$ can be any of $nk-1, nk-2,nk+2,\dots, nk-(n-1)$.

For suppose that $m=(k-1)n+r$, where $r$ is the remainder, that is, $0\le r\le n-1$. Since $(k-1)n+r=kn-(n-r)$,
$$\frac{m}{n}=k-\frac{n-r}{n}.$$
We have
$$\left\lceil k-\frac{n-r}{n}\right\rceil =k.$$

Comment: Thank you; what is the theory behind this?

Comment: The fact that we can express any $m$ as $qn+r$, with $0\le r\le n-1$, is often called the **Division Algorithm**. The proof is not hard, a little abstract. If you wish, I can add it. Or you can [**Google.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

Comment: Thanks, André: It is neat to know about the division algorithm.  So what you are saying in your answer is that although $k$ and $n$ are known, it is not possible to exactly solve for $m$ in an algebraic fashion?  Suppose that $k = 501$ and $n = 2$, and that $m = 1001$.  Given just $k$ and $n$ can I solve for $m$?

Comment: I looked again at your post and saw you are using the **ceiling** function, not the floor function. That changes the answer, but not the structure.

Comment: For your previous question, $m$ can be either of $1001$ or $1002$.

Comment: I see, so from your answer, $m$ is dependent on the remainder $r$? The remainder $r$ would have to be known to compute $m$ exactly?

Comment: Yes, that's right, because  there are $n$ solutions for $m$. The rough size of $m$ is determined, but fine details are not.